# C++ destructors as virtual functions?

Tags: c++, destructor, virtual-functions

I just read recently that its a good practice to implement C++ destructors as virtual functions[1]. Why is this so? Is this a general good practice? If not, in what conditions/cases is a destructor to be made a virtual function?

**Reference**

1. https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-07/Afek/Whitepaper/bh-usa-07-afek-WP.pdf

Comment: You should consider reviewing your accepted answer.  There are several other answers that explain that it is _not_ a "good practice" to make destructors virtual.  The current accepted answer does not discuss this topic, and IMHO it is the _more_ important aspect to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a base class has a destructor and it is NOT virtual, then any child class's destructor will not be called if delete is invoked on the base class's pointer.

This can result in memory leaks.

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape()
    {
        cout << "Shape constructor called" << endl;
    }
    // This destructor should be virtual!
    ~Shape()
    {
        cout << "~Shape destructor called" << endl;
    }
};

class Triangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Triangle()
    {
        cout << "Triangle constructor called" << endl;
    }
     ~Triangle()
    {
        cout << "Triangle destructor called" << endl;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     Shape* pShape = new Triangle();
     cout << "About to call delete" << endl;
     delete pShape;
}
```

This will result in:

> Triangle constructor called 
>   Shape constructor called 
>   About to call delete 
>   Shape destructor called

Any resources that should be deallocated in the triangles destructor has now leaked.

Answer (score 7):

Herb Sutter discusses this subject in great detail in his article ["Virtuality."](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm)  Guideline #4 states "A base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and nonvirtual."

If your class isn't designed or intended to be used as a base class then there is no reason to declare it with a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 3):

From Effective C++ by Scott Meyers - "The rule for giving base classes virtual destructors applies only to polymorphic base classes — to base classes designed to allow the manipulation of derived class types through base class interfaces."

It is most likely that if you have any virtual functions in your base class then the base class destructor must be made virtual.

Classes not designed to be base classes or not designed to be used polymorphically should not declare virtual destructors

Answer (score 2):

When your class has a virtual destructor, then you ensure that destructors in derived classes will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Arguably if your entire class hierarchy is POD or has nothing for the destructors to do, you *might* get away with not having a virtual destructor. However, as soon as you want to derive other classes from your class *and* want to use them polymorphically through pointer/reference-to-base, you will have virtual functions anyway, so there is little overhead adding a virtual destructor, and you never know who will be inheriting from you. As soon as *any* derived class requires a non-trivial destructor *and* may be refered to via pointer-to-base, you *must* have a virtual destructor.

Rule of thumb: if you have any virtual functions, add a virtual destructor.

(The point here is that if you have *no* virtual functions, then there will be no way to use derived classes polymorphically, so it will be less likely that an illegitimate child class that requires non-trivial destruction will be deleted via a base class pointer. It could still be done, it's just less likely.)

Answer (score -1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/07/127826.aspx

In this day and age, I think you should make all methods virtual and then think which ones do not need to be.

OK, yeah, I've done most of my OOP in Java.

Comment: "In this day and age", if you don't have performance constraints, don't use C++.  Use Python, Perl, Ruby, C#, VB.NET, whatever.

Comment: Python, Perl and Ruby are completely off the wall here, obviously.  I agree that C# and Java are much better choices than C++ in a lot of cases.  I don't think, however, that using virtual functions is equivalent to dumping C++ all together.  Thanks for -1.

Comment: I'm not arguing that 100% virtual functions is equivalent to dumping C++.  I'm arguing that 100% virtual functions is an indication that you _should not be using C++_.  You're fighting the language, for starters.  Also, all competent maintenance programmers will assume that functions are `virtual` for a reason, and the possibility of an override (especially in a large codebase) adds a lot of uncertainty to a maintenance programmer's job.  Re: the -1, you're welcome.